# How do you get fontsize toolbar on summernote v0.6.0

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, summernote

The example given on the Summernote website is:

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
  toolbar: [
    //[groupname, [button list]]

    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
    ['font', ['strikethrough']],
    ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
    ['color', ['color']],
    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ['height', ['height']],
  ]
});
```

This does not appear to display either the strikethrough option or the fontsize option in version 0.6.0

There is some talk that the fontsize has been extracted to a plugin, but if so I cant find any documentation on how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fontsize option has indeed been separated into a plugin.
There is a file `summernote-ext-fontstyle.js` in the plugins folder of the Summernote download.

This must be loaded **after** the main summernote javascript.

After that you just have to do the toolbar as in the examples given:

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
  toolbar: [
    //[groupname, [button list]]
    ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
    ['etc', ['etc']],
  ]
});
```